# Show text only if page url contain specific word

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I need to show some text on one page only if URL contain specific word. I tried few examples I found on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

So I need to show text on this URL - "/index.php?option=com_registration&task=register"

I tried to write the code to recognise word "register" in the URL, but it doesn't work. The text is visible on all pages.

EDIT: The text I want to show is "Creating account will automatically put you on our bi-monthly newsletter email list.  Please note:  you can unsubscribe at any time."

And it should be located before every content on page.

Comment: What do you mean by "the text is visible on all pages"?

Comment: @Dumisani I tried few examples, and the text is always visible on every page. And I need it to be visible only on page where URL contain word "register"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your URL is - "/index.php?option=com_registration&task=register"
if you are doing it with php

```
<?php 
  $check = $_GET['task'];
  if(isset($check)){
     #do something...
  }
?>
```

Point is to take query from url and check if it is set, you are doing it with GET method this way, so you will take it with $_GET['parameterName'], variable $check will have value of parameter assigned value

Comment: can you give me whole code? I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in *** on line 75

Comment: This is all what you need------------try with $_REQUEST['task'] instead of $_GET['task']

Comment: Thanks! That worked! :)

<?php 
  $check = $_GET['task'] ;
  if(isset($check)){
  }
?>

Comment: Joomla has helper methods to aid developers in maintaining site security.  `$_GET` should not be used within a Joomla application.

Answer (score 3):

You may parse the browser's location URL using the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and then search the `task` parameter's value. If it matches `register`, perform the logic to show the text.

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);

if (url.searchParams.task === 'register') {
  // perform logic to show the text
}
```

*Note that URL API is not available in Internet Explorer. You need to parse the URL params manually in this case, or use a third-party library, such as [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/).*

Answer (score 0):

I really like @31piy's answer, though if you have to support Internet Explorer and don't want to add a whole library just for simple URL matching, you could always use good old Regular Expressions or even `indexOf`.

For you example you could just use a RegEx for "register" or "task=register".

If you want to go for the simple comparison (e.g. contains `task=register`) then I would choose the string comparison:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('task=register') !== -1) {
    // show text here
}
```

If you want to be more flexible regarding the matching you should use a RegEx:

```
var regex = /task=register/;

if (regex.test(window.location.href)) {
    // show text here
}
```

For more information on Regular Expressions I highly recommend using an explanatory tool such as [this one](https://regexr.com).

Comment: This should be done on server side, not client, one of reasons is support from browsers